# Mark problems as "notify me if answer is posted"?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I have found myself often finding interesting questions which I do not have the time to look into myself, but that I would very much like to see the answers to if someone else does. Unless I am mistaken, there is currently no way to mark a question with something like

- Notify me if an answer is posted
- Notify me if an answer is accepted
- "Watch" question (get all notifications that you would get if you were the original poster)

Of course, the site does this automatically for one's own questions, but not for others'. I think this would be a very helpful feature to have. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried [favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)? Changes to favorite questions are [highlighted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/what-does-highlighting-mean-on-the-profiles-favorites-tab), if you sort your favorites by last activity (most recent). AFAIK it is not shown what exactly are the changes, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes). (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) I don't know which changes cause highlighting, but posting new answer definitely does and from my experience I suspect the also posting comments and editing the question do. (Maybe someone knows where details can be found.)

Comment: There is also this feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343). (And other questions [linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/83343) might provide further reading on related issues.)

Comment: A new feature doing this was implemented recently. See: [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406) and [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661).

Answer (score 6):

You can get [RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions/34491#34491) for every page. While that does not cover accepted answers or comments, it does give a partial coverage of new answers (and possibly edits).

You can also add the post to your [favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) and remember to check the page often, it has a similar effect (and I suspect it might be using RSS based mechanism to begin with).

Comment: While this is certainly an okay workaround, I would much prefer the feature being built in to the site, so as to minimize the amount of effort I have to put in.

Comment: @nullUser: I agree, but don't you think that the inbox is *full enough* as it is already? Perhaps it can be set into another tab (like notifications for badges and whatnot), but I am having a hard time to see that happening soon. Maybe...

Comment: As someone who feeds on information, I personally find my inbox to be rather empty. Also, this is something you can choose to do, not something to be forced upon you. Though I do think that more customization in how and when notifications are received would be good. As far as implementing it goes, I can't imagine it taking more than 100 lines and a column in a database to implement this, the biggest concern would be the overhead speed/storage costs. But again, I would like to stress that I think it would be entirely worth it.