# Is there a way to enable desktop notifications for answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

If there is way or if this could be a feature for certain questions would this be possible?

Comment: Somewhat related post on [meta.se]: [Add desktop notifications for Chrome or Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156050).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I downloaded the stackexchange extension for google chrome.

Comment: I'm not a fan of desktop notifications personally, but if I were tasked with setting up something of this kind, I would consider combining a third-party RSS reader with the steps pointed out in [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted)